# Compile C++ Meta Program in VS2010

Tags: c++, templates

I am unable to compile the below program in VS2010. Keeps compiling endless and got into heap not available. Any help is much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>

class function_t
{
public:
    virtual void operator ()()=0;
};

class greet_t : public function_t
{
public:
    virtual void operator()(){ std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;}
};

template<int count, function_t** f> class loop_t
{
public:
    static inline void exec()
    {
        (*(*f))();
        loop_t< count-1, f>::exec();

    }
};

function_t* f;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    f = new greet_t();
    loop_t<1, &f>::exec();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the problem is in your template code:

```
template<int count, function_t** f> class loop_t
{
public:
    static inline void exec()
    {
        (*(*f))();
        loop_t< count-1, f>::exec();

    }
};
```

Notice that you instantiate this inner template:

```
loop_t< count-1, f>::exec();
```

The problem is that you've never defined a partial specialization of `loop_t` that terminates when the loop counter reaches some value (say, zero), and so the compiler just keeps on instantiating more and more versions of `loop_t` with lower and lower values of `count` until it reaches an internal limit and reports an error.  To fix this, you should introduce a partial specialization of `loop_t` to halt when the counter hits some value (probably zero):

```
template<function_t** f> class loop_t<0, f>
{
public:
    static inline void exec()
    {
        // Empty
    }
};
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is right.  Meta programming uses recursion highly, and like recursion, you always need a loop terminator.